# Get an AWS Table Resource using the low-level Client

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

My goal is to get similar object that I get through:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource(service_name='dynamodb')        
self._table = dynamodb.Table(name)
```

but through the `Client` object.
How can I reference a `DynamoDB` table through the low-level Client object?

Here is my code,

```
import boto3

cli = boto3.client('dynamodb')
cli.get_item(TableName=TABLE_NAME)
```

but I get the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in input: "Key"
```

from the [official documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.get_item) I saw that the `Key` is a dictionary of returned properties, but couldn't wrap my head around what it actually represents.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have any primary key in your dynamoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use The primary key attribute values that define the items and the attributes associated with the items.

```
boto_client.get_item(TableName='string', Key={})
```

by client.get_item:

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
client.get_item(TableName='YourTable', Key={'PrimaryKeyName': {'ValueType':'Value'}})
```

where:

- YourTable - table name
- KeyName - primary key
- ValueType - S, N, B, SS, NS, BS,
  M
- Value - your value of item you want to get from table

notice, that if your value is Number you use N but value will be inside quotes anyway

Comment: By "item to retrieve" you mean the table ? I mean I should put there the primary key of the table I wish to retrieve? Should I provide all the field-names? Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelSidorov no, you should provide only primary key=value while getting or qurying items. that's why we started working with table.scan()

Comment: @MichaelSidorov `response = table.get_item(Key={'year': year, 'title': title})`, by the way you can create table instance with: dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb'), then
table = dynamodb.Table('YouTable')
response = table.get_item(Key={'year': year, 'title': title})

Comment: @MichaelSidorov it's not like relative database when you make select * from table; there's similiar command table.scan(), but it returns about 1MB of data and then you can locally filter by it

Comment: My goal is to get the  `dynamodb.Table` object functionality but through the `Client` object as I need the thread stability of the `Client` object. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: @MichaelSidorov didn't I puzzle you?))

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.